# unslider background not stretching (fiddle included)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slideshow

I am using unslider to make a slideshow for my website. For some reason my background image is not scaling to fit the size of the slide.. see fiddle.. http://jsfiddle.net/j9fDP/

im using

```
width:100%;
```

but it is still not working :(
on their website it scales perfectly any ideas what i am doing wrong. please include a fiddle with a working example. Thank you so much for your help!

Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

Adding `background-size: cover;` to `.banner li` should do the trick.

http://jsfiddle.net/j9fDP/1/